# If limit exists then its radius of convergence is this power series

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am confused as to how if $\lim_{n\to\infty} | c_{n} / c_{n+1}|$ exists, then it equals the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n}x^{n}$ How is this so?

Comment: Something is wrong in your question. Do you mean $$\frac{1}{\limsup_{n \to \infty}|c_n|^{1/n}}?$$https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem

Comment: I think he means the ratio test.

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you. But any good solutions, feel free to post for others to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ and let $L = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |b_{n+1}/b_n|$. By the ratio test the series converges if $L < 1$ and diverges if $L > 1$. The test is inconclusive if $L = 1$ or if the limit fails to exist. Now consider the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n x^n$. By the ratio test, this series converges if

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left|\frac{c_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{c_nx^n}\right| = |x|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right| < 1
$$

Therefore, assuming that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |c_{n+1}/c_n|$ exists and is $> 0$, the power series converges for all $x$ that satisfy

$$
|x| < \frac{1}{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |c_{n+1}/c_n|} = R
$$

Clearly, if the limit is zero then the series converges for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and the radius of converge is defined as $\infty$.

Comment: I had Cn / Cn+1 sorry

Comment: If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |c_{n+1}/c_n|$ exists and is nonzero then $1/(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |c_{n+1}/c_n|) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1/|c_{n+1}/c_n|) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |c_n/c_{n+1}|$

Comment: gotcha that makes perfect sense, thank you